# A set of n generators of a subspace of dimension n.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $n$-dimensional subset $V$ IS a basis of this subspace. But what about a set of $n$ generators in this subspace? Is it a basis of $V$ for sure?

Comment: Yes it's a basis for sure.

Comment: Could you provide a proof for it, please?

Comment: What's the definition of a basis do you take?

Comment: A set of linearly independent generators.

Answer (score 1):

If these $n$ vectors aren't linearly independent then there's at least one of them which's linear combination of the other then the set of $n-1$ other vectors still generator of the subspace with dimension $n$. Contradiction. We conclude that this set is linearly independent and generator and then it's a basis.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of $n$ generators were not linearly independent, then some $n-1$ of them also generate the subspace.  This is a contradiction as the subspace has dimension $n$, and so cannot be generated by less than $n$ vectors.

Comment: Why can't a set of $n−1$ vectors generates a $n$-dimensional subspace?

Comment: @MeE: The answer to that question depends on how you define dimension.  Usually, one shows that any two bases of a vector space have the same cardinality, and then you take the dimension of the vector space to be the cardinality of any basis.  If our vector space has dimension $n$, then any basis should have exactly $n$ vectors, so that any generating set should have at least $n$ vectors.